# Почему крашится flutter при попытке открыть созданный ранее pdf?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, flutter, pdf

Я пытаюсь сделать приложение для создания PDF. Используя 3 библиотеки на `flutter`: `pdf 3.10.3`, `path_provider 2.0.15`, `open_document 1.0.6+2`. Код будет чуть ниже. Суть в том, что на iOS все работает отлично, но вот с андроид все иначе: при нажатии на кнопку приложение просто вылетает, а в консоли такой вывод:

```
D/EGL_emulation(32619): app_time_stats: avg=4177.76ms min=631.96ms max=7723.56ms 

count=2
D/DART/NATIVE(32619): onMethodCall openDocument
E/AndroidRuntime(32619): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
E/AndroidRuntime(32619): Process: com.example.testingv2, PID: 32619
E/AndroidRuntime(32619): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.testingv2.fileprovider
E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getFileProviderPathsMetaData(FileProvider.java:664)
E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:695)
E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:645)
E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:449)
E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at com.fsconceicao.open_document.OpenDocument.openDocument$open_document_debug(OpenDocument.kt:37)
E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at com.fsconceicao.open_document.OpenDocumentImpl.onMethodCall$lambda-5(OpenDocumentImpl.kt:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at com.fsconceicao.open_document.OpenDocumentImpl.$r8$lambda$dC68NxXnNWsal4uI2taad3gzBJ8(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at com.fsconceicao.open_document.OpenDocumentImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(32619):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
I/Process (32619): Sending signal. PID: 32619 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Как я понял, все проблемы берутся от провайдера. Я, согласно документации от `open_document 1.0.6+2` сделал все точно так же, как там и описано (просто скопировал и вставил). В папку `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Код манифеста:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:label="testingv2"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.open_document_example.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Создал папку и файл внутри (`android/app/src/main/res/xml/provider_paths.xml`) ну и внутрь просто закинул все из документации ничего не меняя (может стоит):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths>
   <external-path
     name="external_files"
     path="." />
 </paths>
```

Вот сам код приложения:

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show ByteData, rootBundle;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';

import 'creat/create.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final CreaterPdf service = CreaterPdf();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('demka'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final data = await service.generatePDF();
                  service.savePdfFile('fileName', data);
                },
                child: Text('demka'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`create.dart`:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:open_document/open_document.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

class CreaterPdf {
  Future<Uint8List> createHelloWorld() {
    final pdf = pw.Document();
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return pw.Center(
            child: pw.Text("Hello World"),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    return pdf.save();
  }

  Future<Uint8List> generatePDF() async {
    final pdf = pw.Document(); 
    final ttf = await rootBundle
        .load("assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"); 
    final font = pw.Font.ttf(ttf);
    final page = pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Text(
              "Кому-то короче:",
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 14, font: font),
            ),
            pw.Text('Пупкин Олег Букин',
                style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 14, font: font)),
            pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
            pw.Center(
                child: pw.Text("мир",
                    style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 30, font: font))),
            pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
            pw.Text("пока", style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 20, font: font)),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    pdf.addPage(page); 
    final bytes = await pdf.save();
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File("${directory.path}/example.pdf");
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return pdf.save();
  }

  Future<void> savePdfFile(String fileName, Uint8List byteList) async {
    final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    var filePath = "${output.path}/$fileName.pdf";
    final file = File(filePath);
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteList);
    await OpenDocument.openDocument(filePath: filePath);
  }
}
```

На iOS при нажатии на кнопку происходит так:

[image: при нажатии на кнопку на iOS]

В `andriod studio`:
[image: в andriod studio]

Вылет происходит при попытке открыть созданный ранее pdf, но он его не находит и следует вылет (опять же, как я это понимаю). Но как же это решить?

Comment: authority в логе и в манифесте разные. Не в этом проблема? Я так понимаю в манифесте надо поменять.

Comment: Поменял, но не помогло(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем если я правильно понял это должно выглядеть примерно вот так.

> main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'package:testpdf/view_generateg_pdf.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final path = await generatePDF();

            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => 
ViewPdf(path: path)),
            );
          },
          child: Text('demka'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

generatePDF() async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  final font = await PdfGoogleFonts.robotoBold();
  final page = pw.Page(
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <pw.Widget>[
          pw.Text(
            "Кому-то короче:",
            style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 14, font: font),
          ),
          pw.Text('Пупкин Олег Букин',
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 14, font: font)),
          pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
          pw.Center(
              child: pw.Text("мир",
                  style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 30, font: font))),
          pw.SizedBox(height: 50),
          pw.Text("пока", style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 20, font: font)),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
  pdf.addPage(page);
  final bytes = await pdf.save();
  final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  final file = File("${directory?.path}/example.pdf");
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  return file.path;
}
```

> view_generateg_pdf.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:open_document/open_document.dart';
import 'package:pdf_viewer_plugin/pdf_viewer_plugin.dart';

class ViewPdf extends StatelessWidget {
  String path;

  ViewPdf({Key? key, required this.path}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(path);
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.save,
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              await OpenDocument.openDocument(
                filePath: path,
              );
            }),
        body: PdfView(
          path: path,
        ));
  }
}
```

> provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="app_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

- надо добавить `pdf_viewer_plugin: ^2.0.1` в pubspec.yaml

[image: 1 страница]
[image: 2 страница][image: 3 страница]

Comment: Нет, все так же вылетает. теперь в логе выбивает:
E/AndroidRuntime( 6211): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.testingv2/cache/fileName.pdf

Comment: А вы уверены, что файл существует?

Comment: Ну, после вашего вопроса, уже нет. Честно говоря, я не очень понимаю где должен располагаться этот файл. В моем понимании:
pdf - создает сам файл пдф 
open_document - открывает его внутри проекта flutter
patch_provider - создает автоматически документ в локальном хранилище телефона
я с самого утра за экраном, и сейчас я понять ничего не в силах даже(мозги текут)
Поэтому, если я что-то пишу неверно - я заранее извиняюсь. Но поправьте меня, если я пишу глупости, и направьте на путь истинный

Comment: Для начала хотелось бы понять, чего именно вы хотите добиться в результате)

Comment: Кажется, я понял о чем вы говорили, но сначала что я хочу получить: 
Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, как и на iOS открывался созданный pdf в приложении(как показано на скриншоте), а дальше просто была бы возможность сохранить или отправить(как на iOS) этот pdf. К прошлому вашему ответу о существовании файла. Сейчас дополню вопрос и прикреплю данные из дебага. Как я понял, он создает файл, но после не может его найти. Либо же я понимаю это не так.

Comment: отредактировал ответ

Comment: А вообще я бы изучил управление состоянием на вашем месте, например cubit + freezed

Comment: Огромное спасибо тебе!

Comment: Рад помочь! Удачи в освоении flutter!)